# Login to my REST API from my JS app with OAuth protocol

Tags: api, rest, symfony, oauth-2.0

I have built my own REST API with Symfony2. To query this API, user have to authenticate himself with OAuth protocol (three legs flow).

Now, I'm going to develop the front office based on a Angularjs app and I want to use my own Rest API from angularjs. What's the best way to login users to my api from the front office and fetch a token ? 
I dont want users have to authorize my own app.

Does the three legs flow is really adapted for this case ? Maybe is better to support xauth authentication with a username/password login ?

Comment: could you rephrase the question a bit more clearly? ... and leave out the personal stuff making it more general? :)

Comment: what's the best way to authenticate a user from a front app to a REST API which is protected with oauth2 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok after some research, it seems that the most easy way to manage login/authentication between JS client and Symfony2 backend is to use password grant type (thanks @ricoux) which allows user to get a token with an username/password, like this:

```
http://host.com/oauth/v2/token?grant_type=password&username=Bat&password=test&client_id=clientidkey&client_secret=clientsecretkey
```

With [fosoauthserverbundle](/questions/tagged/fosoauthserverbundle), you need to set allowed grant type when you create your client:

```
    $clientManager = $this->container->get('fos_oauth_server.client_manager.default');

    $client = $clientManager->createClient();

    $client->setName('ApiTest');
    $client->setRedirectUris(array('URL' => 'http://callbackurl.com'));
    $client->setAllowedGrantTypes(array('token', 'authorization_code', 'password'));
```

Comment: We're doing oauth resource owner password credentials as well and is working fine. But do you may have a client side snippet how you do the token request? I always get "Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing"

Comment: Here is my client call: 
   return $http.get(parameters.ROOT_PATH + '/oauth/v2/token?grant_type=password&username=' + username + '&password=' + password + '&client_id=' + parameters.API_CLIENT_ID + '&client_secret=' + parameters.API_CLIENT_SECRET);

Comment: @shinework But isn't sending your client_secret a major security risk? You store it in the frontend?

Comment: it not good at all to save the `client_secret` in the front-end!!! Do you have a better idea to hide it?

Answer (score 1):

I try to do exactly the same thing : REST API with symfony2 and a javascript client with angularjs...

As Nisam said, FOSOAuthServerBundle is the best bundle to integrate OAuth2 authorization server in your symfony2 app.

I your case, if you don't want users have to authorise your own app, maybe a client with password grant type is the solution. In theory the password grant type can be used to exchange a username and password for an access token directly, but I never experiment it with FOSUserBundle, and I find no example in the doc.

Comment: I think the most appropriate solution is to use the xAuth way [like Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/oauth/xauth) which allows user to get a token with his login/password. But xAuth isn't supported by FOSOAuthServerBundle ... Another solution is to log users directly on symfony2 backend with a ajax POST request from the javascript client ([with custom login handler](http://jolicode.com/blog/building-a-solid-base-for-a-backbone-symfony2-one-page-app)) and return a access_token but it's a little dirty ...

Answer (score 0):

When you ready to use third party bundles, [FOSOAuthServerBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle) is one of the best solution

Comment: Yes, I already use this bundle for provide token, actually I'm looking for a best way to get an access_token from my front office with username/password login.

Comment: This(http://blog.logicexception.com/2012/04/securing-syfmony2-rest-service-wiith.html) will help you, for what actually you need.
You can customize the section 'Create a new client' Under the TESTING Section

Comment: But the FOSOAuthServerBundle doesn't support XAuth flow (like Twitter for instance) isn't it ?